# How to send email but not submit or save form using InfoPath

Tags: forms, sharepoint, infopath

I have an Infopath 2010 form that is already created. I have a button that should send an email to specific people when values are true but I do not want to submit or save the form until I click the save button at the top of the form. I created 2 rules 1 for the email button and 1 for the save button. The save button works when I want to submit and save but the email button does not send emails when values are true. I would like to only use InfoPath to fix this issue if possible.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OTTB solution for info path. But we can do some more things.

1. On Email button, we submit a data in temp library, **where workflow
   will start and using workflow you can send email**.
2. If you are using info path with code, **than you can do this directly using code**.
3. Create a **simple service** which send email. On email button, just call
   service function to send email.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ali's suggestion. Also, yo ucan use SharePoint Designer workflow on your dummy/temporary library and use that to email the users. It will trigger on "new item". When you use the "send email" button, it will save on your dummy/temporary library and the workflow will trigger.